# Multi laravel projects can use same vendors in one server?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cpanel

Let's say we use addon domains in cPanel.

We will be able to put many Laravel projects in one cPanel accounts as following structure:

```
- Project 1
  * app
  * bootstrap
  ...

  * public
  * vendor
  ...

- Project 2
  * app
  * bootstrap
  ...

  * public
  * vendor
  ...

 .....
```

We can point domains to public directory of each project.
I just wondered if we can use same vendor directory for all projects.
Of course, we should assume all projects used same packages.

I think we include `autoload.php` in the `index.php` file of the `public` directory.

If we arrange project structure well, is it possible to use same `vendor` for all projects?

Comment: You can use only one project with different subprojects. Google around, there are some tutorials for it.

Comment: In theory you can share the vendor directory but in practice it's usually more trouble than it is worth.  In particular, while your projects may start out using the exact same versions of the same packages, inevitably differences will creep in.

Comment: Well, although there might be differences, I think we can share the largest one. Then others will be able to use it.

Comment: But even if you share it then what exactly do you expect to gain?  Bit of disk space?